# Migration from GoDaddy to AWS Route 53: domain lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, godaddy

I did migration from GoDaddy to AWS Route 53. I thought that the name server configuration would be done automatically between AWS <-> GoDaddy. But seems that isn't.

I other words, I didn't follow the instructions in step 4, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-inactive.html#migrate-dns-update-domain-inactive)

Now, my domain/product vanished from GoDaddy and I can't edit there anymore.

**Question: Is my domain lost forever?** **How can I fix it?**

Note: if I `dig` using GoDaddy DNS, I cannot get anwser for my domain. If I force to use the AWS DNS, I get the correct anwser.

```
$ dig @ns57.domaincontrol.com. mydomain.com
(bad answers from godaddy)

$ dig @ns-222.awsdns-27.com. mydomain.com
(correct anwsers from AWS)
```

---

**UPDATE**: I've updated my answer with my current domain **terahorse.com** which should point to *18.204.192.162*

```
$ dig @ns57.domaincontrol.com. terahorse.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @ns57.domaincontrol.com. terahorse.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 20018
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;terahorse.com.         IN  A

;; Query time: 146 msec
;; SERVER: 2607:f208:206::1d#53(2607:f208:206::1d)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 28 10:55:01 -03 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

Forcing DNS of AWS

```
$ dig @ns-222.awsdns-27.com. terahorse.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @ns-222.awsdns-27.com. terahorse.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9333
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;terahorse.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
terahorse.com.      86400   IN  A   18.204.192.162

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
terahorse.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-1071.awsdns-05.org.
terahorse.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-1585.awsdns-06.co.uk.
terahorse.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-222.awsdns-27.com.
terahorse.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-847.awsdns-41.net.

;; Query time: 152 msec
;; SERVER: 2600:9000:5300:de00::1#53(2600:9000:5300:de00::1)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 28 10:56:45 -03 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 195
```

**UPDATE 2 - with answer**

**TL;DR**

I used answer from Michael Hampton♦, to know where to fix.
I just needed to add all 4 AWS Nameservers in the link below:
[image]

Comment: Give us the domain's name so we can take a look. No, the domain's not lost, but the DNS records might be.

Comment: It sounds like your transfer is complete. You should now begin adding/editing record sets in Route 53, if you did not already add them. Otherwise, [disclose your domain name](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) and people will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's interesting. Your domain terahorse.com was transferred to Route 53, but the nameservers have not been changed to Route 53.

You will need to perform the following two steps:

1. [Create a public hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html) for your domain terahorse.com (this *should* have been done before you transferred the domain, but it's possible that you didn't do so). Log in to Route 53 and choose Create Hosted Zone.
2. [Change the domain's nameservers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html) back to Route 53 nameservers. Log in to Route 53 and choose Registered Domains, click your domain, and then Add/Edit Name Servers.

Comment: Great! I didn't know that the second step was necessary. Now my domain working!  Thanks a lot. Note: I'll edit my question adding a quick screen shot with the answer.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to create the hosted zone, recreate or import your DNS records, and then change the nameservers to Route 53's nameservers at the old registrar. Then begin the transfer of the domain to Route 53. This way there is no downtime.